# How to extract string through regex , when lookbehind strings are subset of each other

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like "SHIPPED DATE 1-09-75" or "SHIPPED 2-03-54". And I want to extract the date part.
The code that I am using gives priority to one case (SHIPPED) even if it is followed by (DATE).

```
re.search(r'(?:(?<=DATE)|(?<=SHIPPED)).*','SHIPPED DATE 23-10-90')
Out: <re.Match object; span=(7, 21), match=' DATE 23-10-90'>
```

What can be done in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do a regex find all search on `\bSHIPPED(?: DATE)? (\S+)`, which will match a date following either `SHIPPED` or `SHIPPED DATE`.

```py
inp = "SHIPPED DATE 1-09-75 and SHIPPED 2-03-54"
dates = re.findall(r'\bSHIPPED(?: DATE)? (\S+)', inp)
print(dates)  # ['1-09-75', '2-03-54']
```

Comment: edited the question...date may not be present always..but shipped can.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to just to extract the date.
Below line of code returns any format of the date

```
>>> re.search('\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}','SHIPPED DATE 3-10-1990')
<re.Match object; span=(13, 22), match='3-10-1990'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_pattern = r"[0-9]{1,4}[\_|\-|\/|\|][0-9]{1,2}[\_|\-|\/|\|][0-9]{1,4}"
test_str = "SHIPPED 2-03-54"
date_from_str = re.search(str_pattern, test_str)[0]
```

The above regex would find you the date in any fromat from the string. You can test it on `SHIPPED DATE 1-09-75` as well.